# XSLT for variable length child nodes

Tags: xslt

I am trying to write an XSLT template for the following XML structure:

```
<dealership>
    <division>
        <division_name>BMW</division_name>
        <models>
            <model_no>328i</model_no>       
            <model_no>M3</model_no>
            <model_no>X5</model_no>
            <model_no>528i</model_no>
        </models>
        <salesman>
            <salesman_name>Bob</salesman_name>
            <salesman_name>Jerry</salesman_name>
        </salesman>
        <mechanics>
            <mechanic_name>Greg</mechanic_name>
            <mechanic_name>Mike</mechanic_name>
            <mechanic_name>Sean</mechanic_name>
        </mechanics>
    </division>
</dealership>
```

I need to output it to a HTML table in this format:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Division</th>
   <th>Models</th>
   <th>Salesman</th>
   <th>Mechanics</th>   
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>BMW</td>
  <td>328i</td>
  <td>Bob</td>
  <td>Greg</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>M3</td>
   <td>Jerry</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>X5</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Sean</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>528i</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is there can be any number of models, salesman, and mechanics. So somehow I need to get the node with the most children to know how many rows to create in the table, then I need a way to track which cells in the rows are empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your output HTML doesn't quite correspond to your input. For example, where have "335i" and "528i" come from, and what has happened to the poor old "M3"?

Comment: your right, ive made edits so they match now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of to do it is to call a named template with the row number as a parameter. The template will then check to see if there is any data to output, and if so then build that row of the table and call itself with the next row number as a new parameter value.

This code demonstrates. The output is different from the HTML you show because  yours doesn't correspond to the XML data you have given. As far as I can tell this is correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/dealership/division">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Division</th>
        <th>Models</th>
        <th>Salesman</th>
        <th>Mechanics</th>   
      </tr>
      <xsl:call-template name="row" >
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="row">
    <xsl:param name="i"/>

    <xsl:if test="models/model_no[$i] |
                  salesman/salesman_name[$i] |
                  mechanics/mechanic_name[$i]">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="division_name[$i]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="models/model_no[$i]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="salesman/salesman_name[$i]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="mechanics/mechanic_name[$i]"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <xsl:call-template name="row" >
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Division</th>
      <th>Models</th>
      <th>Salesman</th>
      <th>Mechanics</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>BMW</td>
      <td>328i</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Greg</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>M3</td>
      <td>Jerry</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>X5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Sean</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hear another possible solution.

```
<xsl:template match="/dealership/division">

    <xsl:variable name="maxcnt">
        <xsl:for-each select="*" >
            <xsl:sort select="count(*)" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test ="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Division</th>
            <th>Models</th>
            <th>Salesman</th>
            <th>Mechanics</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()=$maxcnt]/*" mode="row"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../division_name[$pos]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../models/model_no[$pos]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../salesman/salesman_name[$pos]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../mechanics/mechanic_name[$pos]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

The first step is to figure out which child of division has the maximum count of children by it self. This is done by an for-each over all children sorted by count of children. Therefore the first on is the one with most children.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="*" >
        <xsl:sort select="count(*)" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test ="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This is based on a very good explanation from Dimitre Novatchev[(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/781879/2115381)

Comment: Oh thanks. I already start fearing I'm the only one who likes it, at least a little bit. ;-) Btw, is it really this bad in North Dakota?

Comment: Negative - I saw that quote in a movie once and found it funny. :)